# Subtracting Multiple Logarithms

Tags: logarithms

I am asked to simplify $$J=\ln (x^2-16)-\ln x-\ln(x-4), \quad x>4$$
Since each logarithm's argument is non-negative, I can use
$$\ln x -\ln y=\ln\frac{x}{y}$$
and obtain the correct answer $$\ln\frac{x+4}{x}$$
However I tried to get the answer by evaluating the rightmost two logarithms first and get $$J=\ln(x^2-16)-\ln\frac{x-4}{x}=\ln\frac{(x^2-16)x}{x-4}$$ which is not the same.
What am I doing wrong when evaluating it the second way? Does the order matter?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong when evaluating it the second way?

Note that
$$-\ln x-\ln(x-4)=-(\ln x\color{red}{+}\ln(x-4))$$

Comment: So I've misinterpreted the rule? And $-\ln x-\ln y\neq -\ln \frac{x}{y}$?

Comment: @Jacob: $-\ln x-\ln y=-(\ln x\color{red}{+}\ln y)=-\ln(xy)$.

Comment: @Jacob The property (implicitly) requires that the first logarithm have coefficient $1$ (not $-1$); $\ln x - \ln y$ is OK, but $-\ln x - \ln y$ needs massaging.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\ln x \color{orange}{+} \ln y =\ln xy$$ and $$\ln x \color{blue}{-} \ln y =\ln \frac{x}{y}$$

$$\begin{align} & J=\ln (x^2-16)-\ln x-\ln(x-4)
\\ & =\ln (x^2-16)-[\ln x+\ln(x-4)]
\\ & =\ln (x^2-16)-[\ln x(x-4)]
\\ & =\ln (x^2-16)-\ln x(x-4)
\\ & =\ln \frac{(x^2-16)}{x(x-4)}
\\ & =\ln \frac{(x-4)(x+4)}{x(x-4)}
\\ & =\ln \frac{x+4}{x}\end{align}$$